# In three.j,s what exactly does Object3D's traverseVisible() method do?

Tags: three.js

Does it:

- Merely select objects within the camera's view frustum
- Or does it actually do a z-depth type visibility check and only select those that are fully/partly visible on the screen - for a particular view

Comment: It only visits objects where `.visible` is true

Answer (score 1):

You can see what it does [in the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d081c5a3501d272d19375fab1b01fedf9df29b22/src/core/Object3D.js#L523-L537) by clicking on the link at the bottom of the Object3D documentation.

```js
traverseVisible( callback ) {
    if ( this.visible === false ) return;

    callback( this );

    const children = this.children;
    for ( let i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
        children[ i ].traverseVisible( callback );
    }
}
```

It only performs a check to see if `visible === false`, nothing more. There's no frustum or occlusion checks.